# Can I force garbage collector to collect specific object?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Can I force `CG` to collect specific object which is not being in used or not refer by any other object?

Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < properties.Count(); i++)
{
    EntityProperties[i].Dispose();

    //Like this
    //GC.Collect(EntityProperties[i]);
}
```

Comment: You can't. You can force only collection of objects starting from specific generation. And normally you don't even need to do this, as GC itself pretty good handles automatic collection.

Comment: Refer [What is the XY Problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel thanks for your time.. and nice link(XY problem) for my problem(Metal one!). Let me explain my problem in better way. I shall ask another question or edit same question later on.

Comment: If the original question is different that the duplicate question mentioned, you can edit the question and notify me. I'll vote to reopen this question. If question is same *How to  garbage collect a singe object?* Then I'm sorry I can't help, you already have a answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644552/garbage-collection-on-one-object-c-sharp)